# Combine two queries and add a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2e025c53dd8eb8364824f381aecac201)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    category VARCHAR(255),
    event_date DATE,
    sent_date DATE,
    sales_Product_gross VARCHAR(255), 
    return_Product_gross VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(category, event_date, sent_date, 
sales_Product_gross, return_Product_gross
)
VALUES 
("CAT_01", "2017-05-30", "2017-05-30", "500", NULL),
("CAT_01", "2017-06-05", "2017-05-30", NULL, "250"),

("CAT_01", "2018-07-08", "2018-07-08", "700", NULL),
("CAT_01", "2018-07-18", "2018-07-08", NULL, "370"),

("CAT_01", "2019-02-15", "2019-02-15", "400", NULL),
("CAT_01", "2019-03-21", "2019-02-15", NULL, "120"),

("CAT_02", "2019-04-24", "2019-04-24", "300", NULL),
("CAT_02", "2019-04-30", "2019-04-24", NULL, "145"),

("CAT_02", "2019-12-14", "2019-12-14", "900", NULL),
("CAT_02", "2019-12-28", "2019-12-14", NULL, "340"),

("CAT_03", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-09", "800", NULL),
("CAT_03", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-09", NULL, "425");
```

The table displays the `sales` and `returns` in different `categories`.

Now, I want to calculate:

a) the `return_rate` per `month` per `campaign` and store it in a new column called `calc_type` with the name `monthly`. 
b) the `return_rate` on a `rolling 2 YEAR` basis and also store it in the new column `calc_type` with the name `rolling`.

The result should look like this:

```
category       calc_type       year          month       return_rate
CAT_01         rolling         NULL          NULL         0.445  
CAT_01         monthly         2017          5            0.500
CAT_01         monthly         2018          7            0.528        
CAT_01         monthly         2019          2            0.300
CAT_02         rolling         NULL          NULL         0.404
CAT_02         monthly         2019          4            0.480
CAT_02         monthly         2019          12           0.377
CAT_03         rolling         NULL          NULL         0.531
CAT_03         monthly         2020          3            0.531
```

I have created a query for criteria **a)** and for criteria **b)**. Separately, those queries work exactly the way I need it. 
Now, I tried to combine them using `UNION ALL` the same way it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60579887/add-new-column-to-result-and-coalesce-table):

```
  SELECT
  category,
  'rolling' AS calc_type,
  'NULL' AS year,
  'NULL' As month,
  sum(return_Product_gross) / sum(sales_Product_gross) as return_rate
  FROM sales
  WHERE sent_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND CURDATE()
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
  ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;  

UNION ALL

  SELECT
  category,
  'monthly' AS calc_type,
  YEAR(sent_date) AS year,
  MONTH(sent_date) AS month,
  sum(return_Product_gross) / sum(sales_Product_gross) as return_rate
  FROM sales
  WHERE sent_date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND CURDATE()
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
  ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;
```

However, now only the values for `rolling` are displayed in the result. 
What do I need to change in my queries to get the expected result?

Comment: Why `sales_Product_gross` and `return_Product_gross` are `VARCHAR(255)` type. One of numerical types instead should be used here.

Comment: I do not know MySQL well, but you have semicolon in your union after first select. Remove it. And first `order by`. Make proper `order by` at the end and it should work: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=06485918ecbbee35309490d35d88443e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query looks worked:

```
 SELECT
  category,
  'rolling' AS calc_type,
  'NULL' AS year,
  'NULL' As month,
  sum(return_Product_gross) / sum(sales_Product_gross) as return_rate
  FROM sales
  WHERE sent_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND CURDATE()
  GROUP BY category, year, month
UNION ALL
  SELECT
  category,
  'monthly' AS calc_type,
  YEAR(sent_date) AS year,
  MONTH(sent_date) AS month,
  sum(return_Product_gross) / sum(sales_Product_gross) as return_rate
  FROM sales
  WHERE sent_date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND CURDATE()
  GROUP BY category, year, month
ORDER BY category, calc_type DESC, year, month;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e003e3b5352b86f33cab7e0e2e99c372)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3ef959bb5a6e42e4798cbcb11108bf99

Comment: And how is that query different from the OP's query? Code-only answers tend to be low quality, both for the current user asking the question and for future users with similar issues. An explanation of your solution adds significant value to your answer.

Comment: Difference is in the ORDER BY clause. I used it below each query but in the answer it is below the the UNION ALL. Also I used a semicolon after the first query.